# Requested array size exceeds VM limit when read filesequence

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to read bytes from sequence file with specific key in List. When i'm calling method getCurrentValue, i have getting the OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit. What do i need to read the all bytes to this key.

I was try to change capacity of BytesWritable buf to 1GB, but it dosn't help.

```java
public List<byte[]> read(String path, String key) {
        Path hdfsPath = new Path(path);
        List<byte[]> fileBytes = new ArrayList<>(1);

        Text keyBuf = new Text();

        try (SequenceFile.Reader in = new SequenceFile.Reader(connectionConfig, SequenceFile.Reader.file(hdfsPath))) {
            while (in.next(keyBuf)) {
                if (keyBuf.toString().equals(key)) {
                    BytesWritable buf = new BytesWritable();
                    in.getCurrentValue(buf); //here throw exception
                    fileBytes.add(buf.getBytes());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new HdfsException("When read file, path=" + path + " key=" + keyBuf, e);
        }

        return fileBytes;
    }
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
at org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable.setCapacity(BytesWritable.java:146)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable.setSize(BytesWritable.java:125)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable.readFields(BytesWritable.java:181)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.getCurrentValue(SequenceFile.java:2308)
at ...
```

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone java -server -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx16g -jar ...

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone i make List<byte[]> (list of arrays of bytes), size more part of files is less then 1G, and these files i can read in one step. Does it matter?

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone do you know what is hadooop, hdfs, big data, big files???

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone are trying to earn more reputatuins?